# How to compare two DataFrame (StructType) in python

Tags: python, dataframe, schema

Essentially this is to compare two dataframes, I am able to compare their names with:

```
def diff(first, second):
    second = set(second)
    return [item for item in first if item not in second]
```

But I also want to compare not only on name but also on datatype

Sample dataframe as below:

```
>>> pDF1.schema
StructType(
List(
StructField(Scen_Id,IntegerType,true),
StructField(Flow_Direction,StringType,true),
StructField(Dataset_Type,StringType,true),
StructField(Flag_Extrapolation_Percent_Change_Stay,IntegerType,true)
)
)

>>> pDF2.schema
StructType(
List(
StructField(Scen_Id,StringType,true),
StructField(Flow_Direction,StringType,true),
StructField(Dataset_Type,StringType,true),
StructField(Flag_Extrapolation_Percent_Change_Stay,IntegerType,true)
)
)
```

As you can see from this particular simplified example(often the case our dataframe contains over 100 fields), pDF2 has the same name/datatypeas pDF1, except for the first field, which has different datatype.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the answer is indeed very straightforward as below for future reader's reference:

```
def diff(first, second):
    second = set(second)
    return [item for item in first if item not in second]

dl1_fields = list(pDF1.schema.fields)

dl2_fields = list(pDF2.schema.fields)

print("=========================================================")
print("schema comparison result:")
print("=========================================================")
dl1Notdl2 = diff(dl1_fields, dl2_fields)
print(str(len(dl1Notdl2)) + " columns in first df but not in second")
pprint.pprint(dl1Notdl2)
print("=========================================================")
dl2Notdl1 = diff(dl2_fields, dl1_fields)
print(str(len(dl2Notdl1)) + " columns in second df but not in first")
pprint.pprint(dl2Notdl1)
```